Specifying linear transformation given basis of image and kernel of transformation
The question is formulated as follows:

Find a linear transformation $f: \mathbb{R}^4 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^4$ with $$ im(f) = \langle (1, 0,1,0), \ (0,1,0,1) \rangle \quad \text{and} \quad Kern(f) = \langle (1, 1,0,0), \ (0,0,1,1) \rangle$$

To clarify notation, $\langle \dots \rangle$ means the set of all possible linear combinations of the included vectors.
This raised two geometric questions to my head immediately:

Since only two vectors are specified in the image, does this mean that the transformation effectively maps the vectors from all of 4D space onto a plane?
Is the kernel effectively a lane through this plane?

To my solution attempt: I first thought about solving a linear system to determine possible coefficients of the transformation matrix, but this seemed to be too lengthy and I wasn't getting anywhere fast. It had me stumped, so I looked at the solution in the book, outlined as follows:

We first extend the kernel to be a basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$ by adding the unit vectors $u_1 = (1,0,0,0)$ and $u_3 = (0,0,1,0)$. Then we get: $$ \mathbb{R}^4 = \text{span}\{b_1, b_2, b_3, b_4\} = \text{span}\{ (1, 0, 0, 0), \ (1,1,0,0), \ (0,0,1,0), \ (0,0,1,1) \}$$ We then want to define $f: \mathbb{R}^4 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^4$ such that $$ f(b_1) = (1,0,1,0), \quad f(b_2) = (0,0,0,0), \quad f(b_3) = (0,1,0,1), \quad f(b_4) = (0,0,0, 0). $$ $f$ then has the desired properties. To express $f$ as a transformation matrix $A$, we need the images of the unit vectors. Due to our choice of base, we already have $b_1 = u_1$ and $b_3 = u_3 $ whose images we know. We only need to determine $f(u_2)$ and $f(u_4)$. For this, we can leverage the linearity of $f$ and the fact that $u_2 = b_2 - b_1$ and $u_4 = b_4 - b_3$: $$ f(e_2) = f(b_2) - f(b_1) = (-1, 0, -1, 0) $$ $$f(e_4) = f(b_4) - f(b_3) = (0, -1, 0, -1)$$ Finally, the matrix $A$ is constructed with the images of the unit vectors $f(u_i)$ as its columns.

While the solution makes sense as a whole, I had a very hard time grasping its rationale and would appreciate it if someone were to validate my understanding:

We want to extend the kernel because we want to define basis vectors for $\mathbb{R}^4$ (since that is what $f$ maps to) such that the "kernel line/space" is preserved. We choose $u_1$ and $u_3$ due to simplicity and linear independence from the kernel vectors.
I understand why $b_2$ and $b_4$ must both map to the zero vector, but why does the solution say that $b_1$ must map to $(1, 0, 1, 0)$ and that $b_3$ must map to $(0,1,0,1)$? Isn't it true that it would be valid for $b_1$ and $b_3$ to map to any linear combination of the vectors given in $im(f)$. Are the aforementioned equalites for $b_1$ and $b_3$ again picked for simplicity?

I would highly appreciate anyone's two cents on my clarifying questions.

the answer to question 1 is yes

A linear transformation is determined by what it maps the basis vectors to.  We want to extend the kernel to a basis for $\mathbb R^4$ since that is what $f$ maps from.  We know the kernel maps to $(0,0,0,0)$, so once we have an entire basis for the domain and we know where they map to, the linear transformation is determined.  Yes, we choose the other basis vectors due to simplicity and linear independence

You are also correct that it would be valid for $b_1$ and $b_3$ to map to any linear combination of the vectors given in Im($f$), as long as they are linearly independent, and the choice was just for simplicity

What do you mean by a lane through the plane?  The kernel is in the domain, and the image is in the range

The answer to your question 1 is yes.
Regarding question 2, the kernel is in the domain, and the image is in the range.
A linear transformation is determined by what it maps the basis vectors to.  We want to extend the kernel to a basis for $\mathbb R^4$ since that is what $f$ maps from.  We know the kernel maps to $(0,0,0,0)$, so once we have an entire basis for the domain and we know where they map to, the linear transformation is determined.  Yes, we choose the other basis vectors for the domain due to simplicity and linear independence.
You are also correct that it would be valid for $b_1$ and $b_3$ to map to any linear combination of the vectors given in Im($f$), as long as they are linearly independent, and the choice was just for simplicity.

Note that the question is formulated as find a linear transformation, not the linear transformation

For example, mapping $b_1$ to $(1,1,1,1)$ and $b_3$ to $(1,0,1,0)$ would also work

Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question. I appreciate the clarifications!
